# message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, addsubview, uncaught-exception

Hi i am trying to go back from a subview to main view, however when i put a button action i get this error

```
performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16dd0700
```

here is my code

```
UIViewController *subController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextView"];

 subController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
    ((thrownAtMeItem*) subController).delegate = self;


    [self.view addSubview:subController.view];
```

on the next view i only have a button and in its action im writing nslog.

Comment: Your good friend ARC is destroying `subController` for you, as you don't retain it anywhere. However, the view is being retained so it's still appearing and trying to send messages back to its view controller (`subController`) which has been destroyed.

Comment: Put this line in .h file `UIViewController *subController;` and replace `UIViewController *subController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextView"];` with `subController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextView"];`

Comment: @GuyKogus i agree with your answer guys upvoted too, but just curious how to break this strong reference when remove a subview?As self.view holds strongly subviewcontroller, how to dealloc immediately subviewcontroller , when it is removed from its parent self.view? i know dealloc of view controller.view will be called in the next cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Hold a strong reference to subController as long as you need it. (As long as its view is being displayed)

Comment: i agree with your answer guys upvoted too, but just curious how to break this strong reference when remove a subview?i know dealloc of view controller.view will be called in the next cycle.

Comment: @Alok You break the strong reference by assigning nil to the property that is defed as strong. No need to do that when the object, that holds the reference, is about to be released too.

Comment: so when not case of "when the object, that holds the reference, is about to be released too", how do you tell the parent/superview to make subview nil. i will go for delegate communication pattern to inform superview when subview is removed and in super view class make subview to hill???what will be your approach delegate/notification or some thing else? thanks.:)

Comment: @Alok, the parent/superview may not even have a strong reference. When a view controller object is added to the Array of view controllers the retain count is increased (strong reference if you may say so). E.g. addChildViewController or presentViewController would do that for you. The corresponding remove or dismiss methods will remove the object from the related arrays and therfore "release" them or "nullify" the reference respectively. Just trust the system.

Comment: thank you  very much, reading documents for Viewcontroller containment which encourages to use Containment instead of view controller's view.And then SYSTEM will automatically manage memory/retain-count.